# Enumerate an undecidable set

Tags: code-golf

An undecidable set is a set for which determining whether an object is an element of the set is an [undecidable problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)

Write a program which runs forever, printing the elements of any undecidable set, each element appearing on its own line.  For any element in the set, there must be a finite amount of time after which your program will print that element.  Each element should only be printed once.

Since you have to enumerate the elements, the set you choose will be [RE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE_%28complexity%29).

Some examples of undecidable sets which are RE:

- Programs of any Turing-complete language which halt.
- [Post correspondence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem) instances with solutions.
- Sets of [Wang tiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile) which can't tile the plane.

Comment: What is an example of an undecidable set?

Comment: Added some examples.

Comment: "Programs of any Turing-complete language which halt." So that means we can output `print(1+1)`, `print(2+2)`, `print(3+3)`, etc.?

Comment: @Doorknob can you print _every_ valid Python program that halts?

Comment: @JanDvorak Wait, so the set has to be finite, but it has to be impossible to test whether an element is in the set, but that's contradictory... `set.indexOf(element) > -1`

Comment: The set will be infinite.

Comment: @cardboard_box So I *can* do the `print(1)`, `print(2)`, etc. thing?

Comment: @Doorknob No. The set of valid print-number statements is decidable.

Comment: @JanDvorak No, because the set of all positive integers is infinite, right?

Comment: @Doorknob No.  You'd have to print *all* python programs which halt.  Determining whether or not a python program is in the set described is trivially decidable.

Comment: @cardboard_box but you can't print *all* python programs that halt, because just like you said, the set is inifinite

Comment: @Doorknob you can, eventually

Comment: @JanDvorak No, because if you could, then you could decide whether a program is in that set eventually, so you have solved the Halting Problem

Comment: @Doorknob enumerate all: for each python program that halts, there needs to exist a moment in the execution of your script such that that program is printed.

Comment: I changed the wording. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: ah, thanks @Jan, I think I get it now

Comment: @Doorknob you can't solve the halting problem this way. To prove some program never stops, you'd have to watch your generator for infinite time.

Comment: Does the domain of truth of an unproven conjencture count as undecidable, or we need something that is proven undecidable?

Comment: @JanDvorak it must be proven undecidable.

Comment: so, preferably one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_undecidable_problems)?

Comment: @Jan Yes, but some of those aren't enumerable.

Comment: One more question: does our generator have to be single-threaded and deterministic? Or at least use a bounded number of threads?

Comment: "Each element should only be printed once" - how strict should we be about this? Do we need to filter out two sets of Wang tiles if they only differ in tile definition order? I suppose so. It also makes sense to count rotations and reflections as equal - but this is harder (and expensive) to check. But what about sets of tiles which are only equivalent after recoloring (and 2D rotation and reordering)? Do we need to count `[["1212"]]` and `[["2121"]]` as distinct? Checking for coloring/reordering isomorphism is equivalent to the graph isomorphism problem (_very_ expensive).

Comment: You can count those as distinct or not.  The set of ordered, rotated sequences of Wang tiles which can't tile the plane is still an undecidable set.

Comment: Is the set of Wang tiles that tile the plane periodically undecidable?

Answer (score 4):

#### Haskell, 404 characters

This Haskell program prints all [FRACTRAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FRACTRAN) programs which halt when given the input `2`. (The syntax of a FRACTRAN program is a list of positive rational numbers.)

```
import Data.Ratio
import Data.List
import Data.Either
r=do
 z<-[1..]
 let r=repeat z
 (p,q)<-zip r[1..z]++zip[1..z]r
 if gcd p q==1 then[p%q]else[]
o l=d[map(:xs)r|xs<-l]
e p n=n:maybe[](e p)(find((==1).denominator)$map(*n)p)
h p=map Left(e p 2)++[Right p]
main=mapM print$rights$d$map h$d$iterate o[[]]
d=concat.s
s[]=[]
s([]:b)=s b
s((x:a):b)=[x]:z a(s b)
z[]b=b
z a[]=map(:[])a
z(x:a)(y:b)=(x:y):z a b
```

I have made no great effort to compress this program. Furthermore, the GCD test in the definition of `r` is purely an optimization (it avoids duplicates).

(Also, If you are interested in running it, be sure to compile it, perhaps with optimization; I found that running it in `ghci` quickly consumed gigabytes of memory.)

It operates by successively constructing infinite lists of infinite lists and then flattening them in a diagonal order: the list of all positive rational numbers, the list of all lists of positive rational numbers (all programs), and the list of all evaluation states (including “halted”) of all programs. We then print only the halted states (which are annotated with the program which halted).

Here is the uncompressed and commented version:

```
import Data.Ratio
import Data.List
import Data.Either

-- List of all positive rational numbers
rationals = do
  limit <- [1..]
  let r = repeat limit
  (p,q) <- zip r [1..limit] ++ zip [1..limit] r
  if gcd p q == 1 then [p%q] else []
-- List of all lists of positive rational numbers (all FRACTRAN programs)
programs = diagonal $ iterate oneMore [[]]
oneMore l = diagonal [map (:xs) rationals | xs <- l]

-- FRACTRAN evaluator
evalStep p n = find ((== 1) . denominator) $ map (* n) p
evaluation p n = n : maybe [] (evaluation p) (evalStep p n)
evaluationWithHaltMarker p = map Left (evaluation p 2) ++ [Right p]

-- All evaluation states of all programs
evaluations = diagonal $ map evaluationWithHaltMarker programs

-- All halting programs
haltingPrograms = rights evaluations

main = mapM_ print haltingPrograms

-- from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141287/haskell-cartesian-product-of-infinite-lists
diagonal :: [[a]] -> [a]
diagonal = concat . stripe
    where
    stripe [] = []
    stripe ([]:xss) = stripe xss
    stripe ((x:xs):xss) = [x] : zipCons xs (stripe xss)

    zipCons [] ys = ys
    zipCons xs [] = map (:[]) xs
    zipCons (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x:y) : zipCons xs ys
```

The `Left` values are never actually looked at since we don't care about non-halting states; it's just the shortest way I saw to carry through the incremental evaluation.

Some “future work” if one were trying to write a practical implementation to generate interesting programs, rather than golfing, would be to reduce the needed work by restricting the set of programs under consideration to those which:

- do not have a statically obvious loop (e.g. an integer).
- are unique under “register renaming”; e.g. [3/2, 5/3] is the same as [7/2, 5/7].
- have no dead code under the assumption that the input is 2; e.g. in [5/3, 7/2], 5/3 is dead code because no 3s are in numerators.
- have no dead code due to preceding code; e.g. in [3/2, 5/2], 3/2 will always take precedence over 5/2.

I mention these cases in particular because (other than the looping one) they form the majority of the output. As far as I've run it, it has not produced any output program of length greater than 2.

Answer (score 1):

#### Haskell, 232 characters (with line breaks removed)

This Haskell program prints all solvable Post correspondence problems over the alphabet {A, B}. (Actually, it prints only the ones that actually use every tile at least once. But this shouldn't affect the undecidability of the set.) Each set of tiles is sorted (using Haskell's `sort` function; I don't know how that works on lists of tuples of strings, but it does) and de-duplicated (using `nub`), and the entire list of solutions is de-duplicated as well.

It works by generating all strings, and then, for each string and for each number `n` up to twice the length of the string plus one, generating all pairs of ways to break the string into `n` pieces. The `d` function generates all ways to break a string `s` into a number `n` of pieces. The program takes advantage of the fact that in Haskell, `do` notation on lists simulates non-deterministic choice.

(If I'm not mistaken, "twice the length of the string plus one" is the greatest number of distinct tiles a string can serve as a solution string for. For example, "AB" is a solution string for ("","A"), ("","B"), ("A",""), ("B",""), ("","").)

The `sequence` command, as used right after `s <-` (but not as used right after `main =`), returns all ways of selecting one element from each of a list of lists; for example, `sequence ["abc", "123"]` is `["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3"]`.

```
import Data.List;
main=sequence.map print.nub$do{
n<-[1..];
s<-sequence$replicate n"AB";
p<-[1..n];
u<-d p (s*2+1);
v<-d p (s*2+1);
return.nub.sort$zip u v
};
d 0""=[[]];
d 0_=[];
d n s=do
f<-[0..length s];
c<-d(n-1)(drop f s);
return(take f s:c)
```

With the line breaks, this is 246 characters, but all of the line breaks can be removed.